# Simple way to customize Discriminator column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, discriminator, tph

I'm using EF6 with Oracle via ODP.NET. And I need (and I can't change it) that all db objects would be in uppercase.

I added some conventions and now I have all tables, columns, foreign keys etc in uppercase. All but Discriminator column that generated by EF for two TPH hierarchies.

My question is how I can tell EF to rename this column? I know the way with `Requires(...).HasValue(...)` syntax but I don't want to specify discriminator value for every type (and for every new hierarchy in future). I satisfied with default values, just want to rename column itself.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following convention solved my problem (found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)):

```
public class UpperCaseDiscriminatorConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        if (property.Name == "Discriminator")
        {
            property.Name = "DISCRIMINATOR";
        }
    }
}
```